# JLabel value change on particuar JForm closing event

Tags: java, forms, netbeans

I want to change a jlable value of a form when another form is closing.

to be prasice. assume there are two JForms as frm1 and frm2 and on the frm1 there is a JLable as lab1 and a button as btn1. The default text on the lab1 is "Form 2 is closed" when i click the the button it should show the text as "Form 2 is open" and the frm2 will be visible.

and when click the "x" (from close on top) the frm2 should close and the text on the lab1 on frm1 should change as "Form 2 is closed".

please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used a JForm before but if it is similar to a JOptionPane you can set an int variable equal to it, when it closes/returns it will return an int value which you can check and then implement your code. If it is not similar to JOptionPane in that aspect you can add a window listener. As for actually changing the label, something like this should work:

```
//never heard of a JForm before so i used JFrame as an example
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JLabel label = new JLabel("Form 2 is closed");

JButton btn = new JButton("Click me");
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    //change label text
    label.setText("Form 2 is open");
    //update the frame
    frame.revalidate();

    //open form 2
  }

)};
```

Changing back would be a similar setup.